# How to call Phishtank API to get JSON response?

Tags: api, phishing

It was really painful to find how to call Phishtank API [here](https://www.phishtank.com/api_info.php).
After a lot of searching I was able to find how to call the API. Below is a sample call,

https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/index.php?url=http://auto.smtpsystems.net/&format=json

But the problem with the above call is that it gives the response in XML format whereas I want the response in JSON format.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to use `https` instead of `http` in the endpoint url, although in [Documentation](https://www.phishtank.com/api_info.php) `http` is given(as of writing this).
Use `HTTP POST` request not `HTTP GET`.

And `format` is in quotes(double preferred)

```
# Python implementation

endpoint = "https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/"
url = "http://www.travelswitchfly.com/"
response = requests.post(endpoint, data={"url": url, "format": "json"})
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are making an HTTP GET request. And this method accepts an HTTP POST request

```
//Custom your request

var requestOptions = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    url: "https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/",
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body: {
        url: The URL to check(urlencoded or base64 encoded),
        format: 'json',
        app_key: Your application key
    },
};

//Do the request

request.post(requestOptions, function callback(err, httpResponse, json) {
    //Here you json
})
```

Comment: What you specified still gets response in XML format

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the url, format, and the app_key in the body of the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement their API in my android application with the help of Retrofit. Their documentation is outdated. After spending 3 hours I come to know a few things.

1. use this URL **https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/** (do not use URL with **http://**)
2. use the below interface for retrofit GET request. it does not work with **@Query** and it requires **@FormUrlEncoded**

```
      @FormUrlEncoded
      @GET("https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/")
      fun findPhishing(
                @Field("format") format: String,
                @Field("url") url: String
      ): Single<Response>
```