# How to send request to Phish Tank Api?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to send a request to phish tank and get an answer in JSON format using Python. However, I'm doing something wrong and I have no clue how to fix that. I tried to put the URI after the request URL in the headers but it did not work out.

Does anybody know how to do it properly?

```
import requests
import json

from keys import phish_tank_key

headers = {
        'format': 'json',
        'app_key': phish_tank_key,
        }

def get_url_with_ip(URI):
    """Returns url with URI needed for request"""
    url = "http://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/"
    url += URI
    return url

def send_the_request_to_phish_tank(url, headers):
    """This function sends a request."""
    print(url)
    response = requests.request("POST", url=url, headers=headers)
    return response



new_check = 'https://atsdddatffsd.weebly.com/'

url = get_url_with_ip(new_check)

r = send_the_request_to_phish_tank(url, headers)

print(r.text)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation

```
# Python implementation

endpoint = "https://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/"
url = "http://www.travelswitchfly.com/"
response = requests.post(endpoint, data={"url": url, "format": "json"})
```

Checkout detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982825/14020019)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json
import base64


from keys import phish_tank_key

headers = {
        'format': 'json',
        'app_key': phish_tank_key,
        }

def get_url_with_ip(URI):
    """Returns url with added URI for request"""
    url = "http://checkurl.phishtank.com/checkurl/"
    new_check_bytes = URI.encode()
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(new_check_bytes)
    base64_new_check = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
    url += base64_new_check
    return url

def send_the_request_to_phish_tank(url, headers):
    """This function sends a request."""
    response = requests.request("POST", url=url, headers=headers)
    return response



new_check = 'https://atsdddatffsd.weebly.com/'

url = get_url_with_ip(new_check)
r = send_the_request_to_phish_tank(url, headers)

print(r.text)
```

This code gives output in XML.